# Adjusting height of text to height of image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to grab the height of an image in a video player that the time duration should be half of at any size the player is made. I'm using the following to attempt this, but it is not working:

```
//grabs height of play button and sets value to setHeight variable
var setHeight = $(".play").outerHeight() / 2; 

//appends setHeight variable to time-played and time-total
$(".time-played, time-total").height(setHeight);
```

Current setup: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/11/)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zq2vzkk5/12/

Comment: I can't see what you changed.

Comment: I did not change anything. Just added jQuery.

Comment: I have jQuery in my project, just forgot to add it to the fiddle. That's not the issue.

Comment: Is `time-total` a class? You call it like it was a tag, the dot is missing.

Comment: Somehow it didn't get carried over. That's still not the issue, as neither `.time-total` nor `.time-played` are being acted upon by the adjustment.

Comment: Actually, the real issue is keeping the numbers in line with the timeline control. As you make the player smaller, you'll notice the numbers shift down from where they should be. That is what really needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I think the absolute positioning is causing problems. Have you tried leaving the heights equal and changing the line-height property on the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if I understand your question correctly, I don't thing your need the Javascript snippet at all.

Just position the controls with CSS:

```
.timeline .time-total{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    ...
  }

.timeline .time-played{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
...
 }
```

This works by setting top to half the container height and then translating the element up by half of its height.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvkyvho7/2/)

Comment: Forgot about the `transform: translateY();` property!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed the fiddle slightly. I'm keeping the heights the same and changing the line-height of the time's text.

Is this what you were looking for?

```
$(".time-played, .time-total").height(setHeight*2);
$(".time-played, .time-total").css('line-height', setHeight*2 + 'px');
$(".time-played, .time-total").css('top', 0);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq2vzkk5/14/)

you could just add the styling for the top 0 to your css file like:

```
.time-played, .time-total {
  top: 0;
}
```

and then you could just remove the following line:

```
$(".time-played, .time-total").css('top', 0);
```